# Keeps getting Class Not Found Exception for Postgres driver in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a simple plugin for eclipse, which has one view connecting to Postgres. I have installed postgres which is running fine. I have a driver:
postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar
which was provided with the installation package.

Now I'm trying to connect to database using the code:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    cnfe.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

Of course, I've added mentioned JAR to class path:
right click on project > preferences > Java Build Path
It is added to "Libraries".

Still I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I have also checked the box in "Order and Export" tab.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it's a plugin? Then you should NOT add it to lib path directly like that. You are developing an OSGi bundle and you must open MANIFEST.MF in the manifest editor, then at the Runtime tab, Classpath section, add your JAR. Also check at the Build tab that it's included in the build. Yeah, OSGi, another name for simplicity. Enjoy.

Comment: Great! Thanks alot, it really worked. :-) By the way, maybe you will be able to help me with a similar problem. I have an XML file (XSLT transform) which I want to use in my plugin. How can I include it to the build so it will be possible to use it later in eclipse? For example when creating a new project the file will be automatically copied into it. Thanks again! :-)